# qstring split auto detection?

Tags: qt

How to split a QString by either a comma `,` or a space ?

```
QString line = in.readLine();
QStringList fields = line.split(",");
```

file would be:

```
1.0 2.0
1.1 4.3
```

or

```
1.0,2.0
1.1,4.3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `QRegExp`-based overload of `split`:

```
QStringList fields = line.split(QRegExp(",| "));
```